# Use a Click Event to Add and Remove a Class to individual loop items

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

I want to add a CSS class to a nav menu item each time it's clicked (so i can then style that menu item so people know this is the page they are on).  I know I need to loop through the .menu-item class and add / remove a new CSS class using a loop, but I can't seem to get it to play ball.

I'm guessing I need to make the .menu-item the 'this' object and use a boolean to add or remove the CSS class, dependent on whether the currentItem variable is set to true or false.

I can't seem to get this to play though and I'm not 100% sure I'm using the event listener in the correct way.

Any help would be awesome.

codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/eeKPoo?editors=1010

JS

```
var navlinks = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item')
var currentItem = false;

 for (i = 0; i<navlinks.length; i+=1) {

    function addCurrentItemToMenu() {

    if (currentItem === false) {

        navlinks = this

        this.classList.add('current-item')
        currentItem = true

        } else {

            this.classList.remove('current-item')
            currentItem = false

        }
    }
}

navlinks.addEventListener("click", function(){
    addCurrentItemToMenu() 
}, false)
```

CSS

```
body, ul {padding: 0; margin: 0}

#main-header {width: 100%; height: 100px;}

#mobile-menu-button {display: none;}

#main-navigation {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 5% 10px 5%;
  align-items: center;
}

ul#nav-menu-items {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#main-navigation ul li {list-style-type: none;}

ul#nav-menu-items li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#000;
}

#main-navigation ul#nav-menu-items li a:hover {
  color:blue;
  transition: color .25s;
}
```

HTML

```
<header id="main-header">
  <nav id="main-navigation"> 
    <ul id="nav-menu-items">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="https://www.google.com">News</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="https://www.google.com">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="https://www.google.com">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified codepen for your problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RjJEWe?editors=1010
The code simply add `current-item` class to the clicked anchor, so you can style it however you want in css. You can also see `event.preventDefault()` in the code to prevent anchor from following your link, as it will reload the page and js won't do anything. It depends on the stack that you are using. If you have server backed website, the current link will be handled by the server and html returned will already have the class set appropriately, if you have frontend js framework (Angular, VueJS, ReactJS), you must handle it appropriately.

Just for your example you can see the code below:

```
var navlinks = document.querySelectorAll('li.menu-item > a');

// Loop through all the links and add event listener
navlinks.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Remove the class from all elements
    navlinks.forEach(function(item) {
      item.classList.remove('current-item');
    })
    // add the class to the current one
    this.classList.add('current-item');
  });
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work - it only add's the class to the first nav link.  I need it so that when any one link is clicked the class is added to that particular link and removed from any other links.  Also i need to do it with a loop and not forEach.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: it does exactly what you say, it removes the link from others and adds the link to the one that was clicked though with `forEach`, but you can easily rewrite it to work with `for` loop.

Comment: @TheChewy Here I've added css styling to `current-item` to see the effect: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RjJEWe?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks. I've just realised the problem is I do want the style to stay like that to show the page is active for a particular menu item.  I think i'll have to post another question about how to get javascript to add an active class to a menu item for each page.